# Elegant code to convert Laravel $validation->messages() to array of objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Usually, when validating form requests in Laravel, we can access the errors using $validation->messages().  For example:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#184 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(2) { ["email"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "The email must be a valid email address." } ["password"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(41) "The password confirmation does not match." [1]=> string(43) "The password must be at least 6 characters." } } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" }.
```

Is there some elegant way to convert the object MessageBag to a sample array, such as:

```
[
object({"email" => "The email must be a valid email address."}),
object({"password" => "The password confirmation does not match."})
...
]
```

PS: If in the MessageBag, any field has more then one item, I would like only the first item in the resulting array of objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your definition of elegant, but if you're asking if there's a single function to call on an MessageBag instance to get what you're looking for, I don't think there is. However you may be able to do it in something of a one-liner by mapping the messages stored within the bag like so: `array_map(function ($item) { if (is_array($item)) { return reset($item); } return $item; }, $m->getMessages());` (In fact, because we know the messages are always an array you could remove the `is_array` conditional if you want to.)

Comment: I think so but hope to find more simple decision

Comment: Is it not possible to do `$validation->messages()->toArray()` ? You used to be able to do `$validation->messages()->toJson()`, so I am assuming toArray() would also work.

Comment: Its possible but in fact I'am getting another structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$validation->messages()->all();
```

Comment: @Evgeniy Try the `toArray()` method then. You can find all the methods available in the API documentation: http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html#method_toArray

Comment: I try this of course too. But some conditions from my question are not performed. I think it's impossible without any logic unfortunately :(

Comment: @Evgeniy You’re right. A field can have multiple errors, hence getting an array per key. Just use `array_shift($messages)` in PHP, or `messages.shift()` in JavaScript to get the first message for each field.

Comment: This what I get

    $response = [];

    foreach ($validator->messages()
     ->toArray() as $key => $value) {

     $obj = new \stdClass();
     $obj->name      = $key;
     $obj->message   = $value[0];

     array_push($response, $obj);    
    }

Comment: @Evgeniy I really don’t know what you’re trying to show me.

Comment: of course, we after get all results, we can convert array to string

Comment: This answer is so outdated that `messages()` is no longer a part of Validator.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Wrong. The `messages` method is still there as of 8.x: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L943-L955

Answer (score 2):

Ok, something like this

```
$response = []; 
foreach ($validator->messages()->toArray() as $key => $value) { 
    $obj = new \stdClass(); 
    $obj->name = $key; 
    $obj->message = $value[0];

    array_push($response, $obj); 
}
```

It is not elegant but I do not see another way :)